# DllImport method Throwing Error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dllimport

I attempting to import a DLL into my project but it keeps treating the code as if it there is a syntax error. This doesn't make sense since I am using the example code from the [DLLImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) website. I just wanted to see if it would work but it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
[DllImportAttribute("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint="MoveFileW",SetLastError=true,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true,
        CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool MoveFile(String src, String dst);
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: It says that I am missing a `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can post full source code here and error message?

This test program compiles and run fine:

```
using System;
using  System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class App
{

[DllImportAttribute("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint="MoveFileW",SetLastError=true,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true,
        CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool MoveFile(String src, String dst);

static void Main()
 {
   MoveFile("import.cs","D:\\aa.cs");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out I was placing it inside of another method. Sorry for the lame question.